# A faster cleaner way to replace bind in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance-testing

So i was wondering which is faster bind or apply?  Is there concrete proof (I did about an hour playing around on jsperf, answer below).

Comment: Which is faster? They're two very different things!

Comment: 2 things.  Its funny that i have a -1 on my question and a +2 on my answer...

Second thing:  It is a common thing to want to set scope for a function.  is apply or bind better?  are there alternatives?  That was my goal.

Comment: `.apply()` and `.bind()` are two very different things, though you can use `.apply()` as part of creating `.bind()`-like functionality. The question as posed makes little sense. I don't know why you'd expect to get equal votes on your question and answer, but neither are great... like saying *"...for those too lazy to check out jsperf..."*, when an answer should be such that a person shouldn't *need* to follow a link to get the information.

Comment: I disagree with your statement.  This is not required as part of asking questions.  This reminds me of people who are willing to fight over `{` being on the same line of an `if` statement or on the following.  Its a simple style preference.  The link is to a credible site with plenty of graphs, code, executed code, etc.  That is useful to make an informed questions.

`bind` and `apply` can accomplish some very similar tasks as well as being a huge drain on performance.  If you build performant required apps then this could be an issue.

Comment: *What* is not required as part of asking questions? I didn't give any requirement for asking. I just said that your question as posed makes little sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsperf.com/apply-verses-bind/3

As you can see i have ran several situations, but it turns out that wrapping the function and calling the function on the scope is the fastest (about 2x faster than `bind` or `apply`).

For those too lazy to check out jsperf, here is the results.

```
var myObject = {
    count: 0,
    fn: function() {
        this.count += 1;
    }
};

var bindFn = myObject.fn.bind(myObject);
var applyFn = (function(fn, scope) {
    return function() {
        fn.apply(scope, []);
    }
})(myObject.fn, myObject);
var unboundFn = myObject.fn;
var preBound = (function(fn, scope) {
    return function() {
        scope[fn]();
    };
})('fn', myObject);
```

`preBound` wins by about 2x the speed.  So then i thought of a great utility class.

```
return {
    superBind: function(fn, scope) {
        return function() {
            scope[fn]();
        }
    }
};
```

And boom, super bind :)

Comment: So... What is this intended to be? An instantly self-answered question to get rep points or do you want it marked as community wiki?

Comment: @LightStyle: Self answering is allowed. But the question is very poor. These "which is faster" are often pointless, and very often relative to implementation and version.

Comment: well, as i have been developing very sophisticated apps in javascript i find the `bind` and `apply` functions are used around in code (especially for callbacks and observables).

Second, to light style, i did not know there were any other way.  I went to ask a question, decided to do the research, and found i can self answer.  Since this is, at least i would consider, a good answer to the question above.  I reworded the question above to be simple and to the point for the answer below. 

If that does not suffice i can change that.

Comment: I know that self-answering is allowed, I didn't know it was possible to post a question and answer it in about 5 seconds. Anyway, I just wanted to know if you wanted this to get reputation or to be set as community wiki. If so, you should contact a moderator(I don't have idea on how it could be done anyway). But if you're just looking for reputation well... That's not good ;)